# Getting checks to populate in checkboxes after select statement has been executed in c#

Tags: c#, sql, select, checkbox, populate

I am currently working on a database that has 21 text box inputs and 25 check boxes. I would like to be able to execute a select statement that would populate the text boxes with the correct text as well as populate any check boxes that have the value of one in the database. I am able to search and get the results to the text boxes just fine , however I cannot seem to get a check to pop up when expected. On the database side I have the data types of the check boxes as int , where 1 = checked and 0 = unchecked. Here is a snippet of my code for my select statement.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=CD-FS02;Initial Catalog=engineering;Integrated Security=True");

SqlDataAdapter da;

DataTable ss = new DataTable();


private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    string str = "select * from engineering where (JobNumber like '%' + @search + '%' "
        + "AND DateOrdered like '%' + @search1 + '%' "
        + "AND Title like '%' + @search2 + '%' "
        + "AND PhysicalAddressComplete like '%' + @search3 + '%' "
        + "AND County like '%' + @search4 + '%' "
        + "AND Client like '%' + @search5 + '%' "
        + "AND Contact like '%' + @search6 + '%' "
        + "AND ContactTitle like '%' + @search7 + '%' "
        + "AND MailingAddressComplete like '%' + @search8 + '%' "
        + "AND BusinessPhone like '%' + @search9 + '%' "
        + "AND CellPhone like '%' + @search10 + '%' "
        + "AND Email like '%' + @search11 + '%' "
        + "AND OpenStatus like '%' + @search12 + '%' "
        + "AND CloseStatus like '%' + @search13 + '%' "
        + "AND Cabinet like '%' + @search14 + '%' "
        + "AND Roll like '%' + @search15 + '%' "
        + "AND Drawer like '%' + @search16 + '%' "
        + "AND ConstructionDrawings like '%' + @search17 + '%' "
        + "AND Fee like '%' + @search18 + '%' "
        + "AND ConstructionCost like '%' + @search19 + '%' "
        + "AND ProjectDescription like '%' + @search20 + '%' )";

    SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, con);

    xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtProjectNumber.Text;
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtDateOrdered.Text;
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtProjectName.Text;
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search3", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtProjectAddress.Text;
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search4", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCounty.Text;
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search5", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtClient.Text;
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search6", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtClientContact.Text;
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search7", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtContactTitle.Text;
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search8", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtBillingAddress.Text;
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search9", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtBusinessPhone.Text;
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search10", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCellPhone.Text;
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search11", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtEmail.Text;
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search12", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtOpenStatus.Text;
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search13", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCloseStatus.Text;
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search14", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCabinet.Text;
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search15", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtRoll.Text;
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search16", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtDrawer.Text;
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search17", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtDrawings.Text;
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search18", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtFee.Text;
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search19", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCost.Text;
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search20", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtProjectDescription.Text;

    try
    {
        xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = xp;
        da.Fill(ss);
        Showdata(pos);
        if ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().First()["engineering"] == 1)
        {
            this.chkDesign.Checked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            this.chkDesign.Checked = true;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No Record Found");
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

Any help or knowledge on this would be appreciated.

Comment: You might need to try refreshing the controls. Is this WPF or WinForms?

Comment: it is WinForms.

Comment: Try calling this.chkDesign.Update() after you set Checked

Comment: Step through your code in the debugger and find out what's actually happening. There aren't any subtleties here. If `this.chkDesign` is a checkbox and you're setting `this.chkDesign.Checked = true;`, it will be checked.

Comment: Why are you calling `xp.ExecuteNonQuery()` for a `SELECT`? What is `Showdata(pos);`?

Comment: Can you specify where I would try calling this ? sorry I am still fairly new to this!

Comment: Call after this.chkDesign.Checked = true; and this.chkDesign.Checked = false;

Comment: Also Ed , the Showdata(pos) is there so that I can have the ability of tabbing through results if the query returns more than one record. And I am calling xp.ExecuteNonQuery() because that is the only way I learned.

Comment: Your problem is in the line if ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().First()["engineering"] == 1).  Are you sure there is a column named "engineering"?  isn't that the name of the table?  And the executenonquery will execute the sql statement, but will only return the number of rows affected, which you do not use.  It is unnecessary.

Comment: @brandonstrong I tried calling after those but still did't return a checked box. Every time I run a query now it returns the message "No record found" even when the text boxes populate.  If I take out  if ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().First()["engineering"] == 1)
        {
            this.chkDesign.Checked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            this.chkDesign.Checked = true;
        }           it runs fine.

Comment: What is the name of the column you are really trying to test on, in order to check the checkbox?

Comment: @AgapwIesu Yes you are  right , I was using the table name instead of the column name....... Now when I run the query it works perfectly , I appreciate the help!!

Comment: @AgapwIesu however , now I am running into a problem where I am getting the " no record found " message when running a query that contains no checkbox values. Is there any way to make it stop?

Comment: Yes.  That should probably be a separate question, but I will go ahead and answer.  I'll modify my answer.  Just have to check to make sure the query returned any rows before you try to use the first one.  Does SS have any rows in it?

Comment: Would you please accept the answer, and/or up-vote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, inside the try, should probably read something like this:

```
    // xp.ExecuteNonQuery();  //this is unnecessary
    // the sql query will get executed by the da.Fill command.
    da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = xp;
    da.Fill(ss);
    Showdata(pos);
    if (ss.Rows.Count > 0) {
      this.chkDesign.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().First()["Design"] == 1);
    }
```

You actually have to check to see if the query returned any rows before you try to use the first one.  i am not sure I have the syntax quite right, but you get the idea.

Comment: How would I continue this code to check for the rest of the 24 checkboxes?